# Random Quote Won't Display

Tags: javascript, jquery

My random quoter's not working (should display a random quote each click of the button). What's going on? My colleagues are stumped, too. It worked when in javascript form, but when converting all syntax to jquery it's not working.

HTML is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" manifest="quoter.manifest">
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <title>Quoter</title>

        <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <section>

            <header>
                <div id="padmeheader"><h1>Bennett's Quoter</h1></div>
                <nav></nav>
            </header>

            <main>
            <div id="centerme">
                <button id="submit" type="button">Get new quote!</button>
                <span id="quoteText"></span> 
                <span id="authorText"></span> 
            </div>
            </main>

            <footer>
                &copy; 2014 
            </footer>

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

Jquery is here:

```
$(function() 
{
    var quoteSpan     = $("quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
    var authorSpan    = $("authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
    var submitButton  = $('submit'); //assign var to button

    var oldQuoteIndex = -1;
    var newQuoteIndex;

    var quotes        = [
        {'text': '"Whatever you are, be a good one."', 'author': '-Abraham Lincoln'}, 
        {'text': '"It has been my philosophy of life that difficulties vanish when faced boldly."', 'author': '-Isaac Asimov'}, 
        {'text': '"Enjoy life. There’s plenty of time to be dead."', 'author': '-Anonymous'}, 
        {'text': '"Every moment is a fresh beginning."', 'author': '-T.S. Eliot'}, 
        {'text': '"One day your life will flash before your eyes. Make sure it is worth watching."', 'author': '-Anonymous'}
    ];  

    quoteSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].text); //make HTML's quoteText random quote
    authorSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].author); //make HTML's authorText random author

    function nextQuote() {
        do {
            newQuoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        } while (newQuoteIndex == oldQuoteIndex); //if new index is duplicated, choose a new index

        quoteSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].text); //make HTML's quoteText random quote
        authorSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].author); //make HTML's authorText random author

        oldQuoteIndex = newQuoteIndex; //make both indexes same, so 'while' randomizer executes every time
   }
    submitButton.click(nextQuote);
    nextQuote();
});
```

CSS is here:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:black !important;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:red !important;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:green !important;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color:blue !important;
    background-color:white !important;
}

body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    /*margin:1em 1em 1em 1em;*/
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: verdana;
    color:black;    
}

footer {
    bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:200px;
    position:absolute;
}

#quoteText {
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:3em;
    color:black;
    width:600px;
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
} 

#authorText {
    font-style:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:grey;
    width:600px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
} 

#centerme {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    width:600px;
}

#submit {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:1.3em;
}

#padmeheader {
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

h1 {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

Comment: If it worked in javascript, why would you convert it in jQuery?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Because learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting items by ID in jquery, you need to use a "#".  For instance, it should be:

```
var submitButton = $("#submit")
```

It uses the standard CSS syntax for [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("submitButton");
$("quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
$("authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
```

should be

```
$("#submitButton");
$("#quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
$("#authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
```

ID Selectors need to have a hashtag before the ID, otherwise it's looking for an element of type quoteText

Answer (score 3):

Many answers, such as @Kith's, have pointed out that your selectors are incorrect, but you also are trying to access the `quotes` array with an undefined variable.

```
var oldQuoteIndex = -1;
var newQuoteIndex;

var quotes = ...

//newQuoteIndex is undefined here.
quoteSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].text); //make HTML's quoteText random quote
authorSpan.html(quotes[newQuoteIndex].author);
```

Since you are calling `nextQuote();` at the end of the doc ready function, these 2 lines are redundant anyway and should be removed.

Comment: newQuoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        
It should be defined there.

EDIT: Nevermind, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @kith But that is in a function defined after first use of newQuoteIndex

Answer (score 2):

The problem is right here :

```
var quoteSpan     = $("quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
var authorSpan    = $("authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
var submitButton  = $('submit'); //assign var to button
```

You are selecting DOM node named `quoteText`, `authorText` and `submit` while what you want are the `id`:

```
var quoteSpan     = $("#quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
var authorSpan    = $("#authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
var submitButton  = $('#submit'); //assign var to button
```

Please take a look at all the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the selectors correctly using # for ID and . for class

```
var quoteSpan     = $("#quoteText"); //assign var to quoteText id contents
var authorSpan    = $("#authorText"); //assign var to authorText id contents
var submitButton  = $('#submit'); //assign var to button
```